# Creating a trigger in order to maintain an intermediate table integrity

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I've created a database with the following diagram:

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x489q90/440/o1yu.png

The `TrainerPokemon` table represents an occurrence of a pokemon (that belongs to a trainer), while the `Pokemon` table represents a pokemon 'specie'. One certain specie of pokemon may have access to certain abilities, but an occurrence of this pokemon may carry only one ability (column `AbilityID` on the `TrainerPokemon` table).

Here's my problem: I was trying to create a trigger in order to prevent that any other ability (different from what is specified in the `PokemonAbility` table) is inserted/updated to a register in the `TrainerPokemon` table, but I did not have success.
Does anyone has any idea for a trigger? New ideas for this database model are welcome as well.
(Important Note: I am using SQL Server 2012)

Comment: You shouldn't use a trigger here, you should fix your schema. The `AbilityId` column on the `TrainerPokemon` table should really be the `ID` of the `PokemonAbility` table and it should reference that column. (That leaves the issue that you could end with an ability that's different for the pokemon there, but that's how you modeled your diagram)

Comment: So what should I use to maintain the data integrity?

Comment: For the particular case you explained here, to add the reference that I just said. Sadly, I don't have the time to look at your whole schema, understand what is that you actually want and then create a new diagram

Comment: PeeeeeeeeeekaCHUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU!

Comment: To achieve what you need, you should really merge tables `TrainerPokemon` and `PokemonAbility`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (typing off the top of my head):

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_pok_abil ON TrainerPokemon FOR UPDATE, INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM inserted
        WHERE inserted.AbilityID NOT (
            SELECT AbilityID
            FROM PokemonAbility
            WHERE PokemonAbility.PokemonID = inserted.PokemonID
        )
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK
    END
END
```

Comment: It's often helpful to toss in a `RaIsError` statement that explains why the operation failed.

Comment: Agreed. Was just a quick effort tbh

Comment: What should be the table 'inserted'? I've tried to substitute it for TrainerPokemon, but then it will be impossible to bond with

Comment: "inserted" is a system table representing the added rows. "deleted" represents the removed rows. So an update will have a "deleted" table and an "inserted" table.

Comment: In other words, do it exactly as I said, no changes required.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a two column foreign key constraint between pokemonability and trainerpokemon on pokemonid, abilityid.

HTH

Comment: That  could wrongly pick up an unrelated pokemon/ability combination

Comment: I actually think the ERD needs some revision. The pokemonability pokemontrainer may need to be merged into one table with alogicl key of pokemon, trainer ability depending on the cardinality. Ie can a pokemon have the more than one trainer for an ability. At a guess pokemantypes shouldn't be a separate table unless a pokemon can have multiple types.